# Selecting a subset of rows that exceed a percentage of total values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cumulative-sum

I have a table with customers, users and revenue similar to below (in reality thousands of records):

```
Customer   User    Revenue
001        James   500
002        James   750
003        James   450
004        Sarah   100
005        Sarah   500
006        Sarah   150
007        Sarah   600
008        James   150
009        James   100
```

What I want to do is to return only the highest spending customers that make up 80% of the total revenue for the user.

To do this manually I would order James' customers by their revenue, work out the percentage of total and a running total percentage, then only return records up to the point that the running total hits 80%:

```
Customer    User    Revenue     % of total  Running Total %
002         James   750         0.38        0.38 
001         James   500         0.26        0.64 
003         James   450         0.23        0.87  <- Greater than 80%, last record
008         James   150         0.08        0.95 
009         James   100         0.05        1.00
```

I've tried using a CTE but so far have come up blank. Is there any way to do this via a single query rather than manually in an Excel sheet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`SQL Server 2012+` only**

You could use windowed `SUM`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
          1.0 * Revenue/SUM(Revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY [User]) AS percentile,
          1.0 * SUM(Revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Revenue] DESC)
                /SUM(Revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY [User]) AS running_percentile
   FROM tab
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE running_percentile <= 0.8;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/IDYCVJ26861)**</kbd>

---

SQL Server 2008:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Revenue DESC) AS rn
    FROM t    
), cte2 AS
(
    SELECT c.Customer, c.[User], c.[Revenue]
           ,percentile         = 1.0 * Revenue / NULLIF(c3.s,0)
           ,running_percentile = 1.0 * c2.s    / NULLIF(c3.s,0)
    FROM cte c
    CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS s
          FROM cte c2
          WHERE c.[User] = c2.[User]
            AND c2.rn <= c.rn) c2
    CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS s
          FROM cte c2
          WHERE c.[User] = c2.[User]) AS c3
) 
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE running_percentile <= 0.8;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/TUQ82944)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Customer ║ User  ║ Revenue ║   percentile   ║ running_percentile ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║        2 ║ James ║     750 ║ 0,384615384615 ║ 0,384615384615     ║
║        1 ║ James ║     500 ║ 0,256410256410 ║ 0,641025641025     ║
║        7 ║ Sarah ║     600 ║ 0,444444444444 ║ 0,444444444444     ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

> *That looks nearly there, the only niggle is **it's missing the last row**,
>   the third row for James takes him over 0.80 but needs to be included.*

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Revenue DESC) AS rn
    FROM t    
), cte2 AS
(
    SELECT c.Customer, c.[User], c.[Revenue]
           ,percentile         = 1.0 * Revenue / NULLIF(c3.s,0)
           ,running_percentile = 1.0 * c2.s    / NULLIF(c3.s,0)
    FROM cte c
    CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS s
          FROM cte c2
          WHERE c.[User] = c2.[User]
            AND c2.rn <= c.rn) c2
    CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS s
          FROM cte c2
          WHERE c.[User] = c2.[User]) AS c3
) 
SELECT a.*
FROM cte2 a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(running_percentile) AS rp
             FROM cte2
             WHERE running_percentile >= 0.8
               AND cte2.[User] = a.[User]) AS s
WHERE a.running_percentile <= s.rp;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](http://rextester.com/HNX71276)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Customer ║ User  ║ Revenue ║   percentile   ║ running_percentile ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║        2 ║ James ║     750 ║ 0,384615384615 ║ 0,384615384615     ║
║        1 ║ James ║     500 ║ 0,256410256410 ║ 0,641025641025     ║
║        3 ║ James ║     450 ║ 0,230769230769 ║ 0,871794871794     ║
║        7 ║ Sarah ║     600 ║ 0,444444444444 ║ 0,444444444444     ║
║        5 ║ Sarah ║     500 ║ 0,370370370370 ║ 0,814814814814     ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

---

> Looks to be perfect, translated to my big table and returns what I need, spent a good 5 minutes working through it and **still can't follow what you've done!**

`SQL Server 2008` does not support everything in `OVER()` clause, but `ROW_NUMBER` does.

First cte just calculate position within a group:

```
╔═══════════╦════════╦══════════╦════╗
║ Customer  ║ User   ║ Revenue  ║ rn ║
╠═══════════╬════════╬══════════╬════╣
║        2  ║ James  ║     750  ║  1 ║
║        1  ║ James  ║     500  ║  2 ║
║        3  ║ James  ║     450  ║  3 ║
║        8  ║ James  ║     150  ║  4 ║
║        9  ║ James  ║     100  ║  5 ║
║        7  ║ Sarah  ║     600  ║  1 ║
║        5  ║ Sarah  ║     500  ║  2 ║
║        6  ║ Sarah  ║     150  ║  3 ║
║        4  ║ Sarah  ║     100  ║  4 ║
╚═══════════╩════════╩══════════╩════╝
```

Second cte:

- `c2` subquery calculate running total based on rank from `ROW_NUMBER`
- `c3` calculate full sum per user

In final query `s` subquery finds the lowest `running` total that exceeds 80%.

**EDIT 3:**

Using `ROW_NUMBER` is actually redundant.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT c.Customer, c.[User], c.[Revenue]
           ,percentile         = 1.0 * Revenue / NULLIF(c3.s,0)
           ,running_percentile = 1.0 * c2.s    / NULLIF(c3.s,0)
    FROM t c
    CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS s
          FROM t c2
          WHERE c.[User] = c2.[User]
            AND c2.Revenue >= c.Revenue) c2
    CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS s
          FROM t c2
          WHERE c.[User] = c2.[User]) AS c3
) 
SELECT a.*
FROM cte a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(running_percentile) AS rp
             FROM cte c2
             WHERE running_percentile >= 0.8
               AND c2.[User] = a.[User]) AS s
WHERE a.running_percentile <= s.rp
ORDER BY [User], Revenue DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo4`](http://rextester.com/AZM93478)**</kbd>

Comment: That looks nearly there, the only niggle is it's missing the last row, the third row for James takes him over 0.80 but needs to be included. If this isn't possible though it's not a disaster.

Comment: Looks to be perfect, translated to my big table and returns what I need, spent a good 5 minutes working through it and still can't follow what you've done! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use the cumulative sum -- much more efficient.  In SQL Server 2008, you can do this using a correlated subquery or `cross apply`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(t.Revenue*1.0) / sum(t.Revenue) over (partition by user) as [% of Total],
       sum(RunningRevenue*1.0) / sum(t.Revenue) over (partition by user) as [Running Total %]
from t cross apply
     (select sum(Revenue) as RunningRevenue
      from t t2
      where t2.Revenue >= t.Revenue and t2.user = t.user
     ) t2;
```

Note:  The `*1.0` is just in case `Revenue` is stored as an integer.  SQL Server does integer division, which would return `0` for both columns on almost all rows.

EDIT:

Add `where user = 'James'` if you want results only for James.

Comment: The `[% of Total]` column seems to work but only for a single user, the running total seems to be all over the place though.

Comment: @bendataclear . . . Your original question only had one user.  It is trivial to adjust this for running totals for a single user.  And much simpler than lad's answer.

Comment: First `sum` around `t.Revenue` is not necessary. It won't work becasue there is no `GROUP BY` (or I miss something). Second `user` should be quoted `[user]` otherwise you will get error. Third:  `SUM OVER()` calculates percentage per entire not table not per `user`. And there is no filtering.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Of course this works.  This is an `apply` using an aggregation for each row.  You may want to review the documentation on `apply` (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) or try it yourself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please check **[Demo](http://rextester.com/XFMIR65799)**. Even if you remove `sum` and add wrap  `user` with `[]` the result of percentage will be for entire table `sum(t.Revenue) over ()`. The case is that in current form the code does not even run.

Comment: And second **[demo](http://rextester.com/GTHXEE91369)**. Please check `[% of Total]` and `[Running Total %]`.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . As I pointed out in an earlier comment, the original question was only about one user.  The answer is adjusted for the appropriate `partition by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please correct obvious mistakes that I pointed out.  `sum(t.Revenue*1.0)` should be `t.Revenue*1.0`. Second you cannot use `user` in TSQL. It has to be quouted `[user]`/`"user"`. I know that you write code by hand. But after adding demos you should check it. As you wrote before in comment above: `try it yourself`.

Comment: And second maybe I miss something but orignial question has `Sarah` from the beginning. It is not in the resultset but even then you should add `WHERE` condition to your initial query to filter only `James`.