# SQL Server - conditional aggregation with correlation

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, sql

Background:

The [original case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452626/selecting-a-subset-of-rows-that-exceed-a-percentage-of-total-values) was very simple. Calculate running total per user from highest revenue to lowest:

```
CREATE TABLE t(Customer INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
              ,"User"   VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
              ,Revenue  INTEGER  NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO t(Customer,"User",Revenue) VALUES
(001,'James',500),(002,'James',750),(003,'James',450),
(004,'Sarah',100),(005,'Sarah',500),(006,'Sarah',150),
(007,'Sarah',600),(008,'James',150),(009,'James',100);
```

Query:

```
SELECT *,
    1.0 * Revenue/SUM(Revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY "User") AS percentage,
    1.0 * SUM(Revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY "User" ORDER BY Revenue DESC)
         /SUM(Revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY "User") AS running_percentage
FROM t;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/ZMUJW38298)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ User  ║ Revenue ║ percentage ║ running_percentage ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════════╬════════════════════╣
║  2 ║ James ║     750 ║ 0.38       ║ 0.38               ║
║  1 ║ James ║     500 ║ 0.26       ║ 0.64               ║
║  3 ║ James ║     450 ║ 0.23       ║ 0.87               ║
║  8 ║ James ║     150 ║ 0.08       ║ 0.95               ║
║  9 ║ James ║     100 ║ 0.05       ║ 1                  ║
║  7 ║ Sarah ║     600 ║ 0.44       ║ 0.44               ║
║  5 ║ Sarah ║     500 ║ 0.37       ║ 0.81               ║
║  6 ║ Sarah ║     150 ║ 0.11       ║ 0.93               ║
║  4 ║ Sarah ║     100 ║ 0.07       ║ 1                  ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

It could be calculated differently using specific windowed functions.

---

Now let's assume that we cannot use windowed `SUM` and rewrite it:

```
SELECT c.Customer, c."User", c."Revenue"
    ,1.0 * Revenue / NULLIF(c3.s,0) AS percentage
    ,1.0 * c2.s    / NULLIF(c3.s,0) AS running_percentage
FROM t c
CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS s
        FROM t c2
        WHERE c."User" = c2."User"
            AND c2.Revenue >= c.Revenue) AS c2
CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS s
        FROM t c2
        WHERE c."User" = c2."User") AS c3
ORDER BY "User", Revenue DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/KPEK4632)**</kbd>

I have used `CROSS APPLY` because I do not like correlated subqueries in `SELECT` colums list and `c3` is used twice.

Everything work as it should. But when we look closer `c2` and `c3` are very similiar. So why not combine them and use simple conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.Customer, c."User", c."Revenue"
    ,1.0 * Revenue        / NULLIF(c2.sum_total,0) AS percentage
    ,1.0 * c2.sum_running / NULLIF(c2.sum_total,0) AS running_percentage
FROM t c
CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS sum_total,
                SUM(CASE WHEN c2.Revenue >= c.Revenue THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END) 
                AS sum_running
        FROM t c2
        WHERE c."User" = c2."User") AS c2
ORDER BY "User", Revenue DESC;
```

Unfortunately it is not possible.

> Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Of course I could circumvent it wrapping with another subquery, but it becomes a bit "ugly":

```
SELECT c.Customer, c."User", c."Revenue"
    ,1.0 * Revenue        / NULLIF(c2.sum_total,0) AS percentage
    ,1.0 * c2.sum_running / NULLIF(c2.sum_total,0) AS running_percentage
FROM t c
CROSS APPLY
(   SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS sum_total,
           SUM(running_revenue) AS sum_running
     FROM (SELECT Revenue,
                  CASE WHEN c2.Revenue >= c.Revenue THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END 
                  AS running_revenue
           FROM t c2
           WHERE c."User" = c2."User") AS sub
) AS c2
ORDER BY "User", Revenue DESC
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/YRKO76442)**</kbd>

---

`Postgresql` version. The only difference is `LATERAL` instead of `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT c.Customer, c."User", c.Revenue
    ,1.0 * Revenue        / NULLIF(c2.sum_total,0) AS percentage 
    ,1.0 * c2.running_sum / NULLIF(c2.sum_total,0) AS running_percentage 
FROM t c
,LATERAL (SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS sum_total,
                 SUM(CASE WHEN c2.Revenue >= c.Revenue THEN c2.Revenue ELSE 0 END) 
                 AS running_sum
        FROM t c2
        WHERE c."User" = c2."User") c2
ORDER BY "User", Revenue DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8cab1/2/0)**</kbd>

It works very nice.

---

`SQLite`/`MySQL` version (that is why I prefer`LATERAL/CROSS APPLY`):

```
SELECT c.Customer, c."User", c.Revenue,
    1.0 * Revenue / (SELECT SUM(Revenue)
                     FROM t c2
                     WHERE c."User" = c2."User") AS percentage,
    1.0 * (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c2.Revenue >= c.Revenue THEN c2.Revenue ELSE 0 END)
           FROM t c2
          WHERE c."User" = c2."User")  / 
          (SELECT SUM(c2.Revenue)
           FROM t c2
           WHERE c."User" = c2."User") AS running_percentage
FROM t c
ORDER BY "User", Revenue DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddleDemo-SQLite`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/94a35/1/0)**</kbd>  <kbd>**[`SQLFiddleDemo-MySQL`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c85e83/5/0)**</kbd>

---

I've read [Aggregates with an Outer Reference](http://sqlmag.com/blog/aggregates-outer-reference):

> The source for the restriction is in the `SQL-92` standard, and `SQL Server` inherited it from the `Sybase` codebase. The problem is that SQL Server needs to figure out which query will compute the aggregate.

I do not search for answers that **only** show how to circumvent it.

The questions are:

1. Which part of standard disallow or interfere with it?
2. Why other RDBMSes do not have problem with this kind of outer dependency?
3. Do they extend `SQL Standard` and `SQL Server` behaves as it should or `SQL Server` does not implement it fully(correctly?)?.

I would be very grateful for references to:

- `ISO standard` (92 or newer)
- [SQL Server Standards Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh501587%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- official documenation from any RDBMS that explains it (`SQL Server/Postgresql/Oracle/...`).

**EDIT:**

I know that `SQL-92` does not have concept of `LATERAL`. But version with subqueries (like in `SQLite/MySQL`) does not work too.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/ZAOJ48675)**</kbd>

**EDIT 2:**

To simplify it a bit, let's check only correlated subquery only:

```
SELECT c.Customer, c."User", c.Revenue,
       1.0*(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c2.Revenue >= c.Revenue THEN c2.Revenue ELSE 0 END)
              FROM t c2
              WHERE c."User" = c2."User") 
       / (SELECT SUM(c2.Revenue)
          FROM t c2
          WHERE c."User" = c2."User") AS running_percentage
FROM t c
ORDER BY "User", Revenue DESC;
```

The version above works fine in `MySQL/SQLite/Postgresql`.

In `SQL Server` we get error. After wraping it with subquery to "flatten" it to one level it works:

```
SELECT c.Customer, c."User", c.Revenue,
      1.0 * (
              SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN r1 >= r2 THEN r1 ELSE 0 END)
              FROM (SELECT c2.Revenue AS r1, c.Revenue r2
                    FROM t c2
                    WHERE c."User" = c2."User") AS S)  / 
             (SELECT SUM(c2.Revenue)
              FROM t c2
              WHERE c."User" = c2."User") AS running_percentage
FROM t c
ORDER BY "User", Revenue DESC;
```

The point of this question is how does `SQL standard` regulate it.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/WFYP90759)**</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier solution:

```
SELECT c.Customer, c."User", c."Revenue",
       1.0 * Revenue/ NULLIF(c2.sum_total, 0) AS percentage,
       1.0 * c2.sum_running / NULLIF(c2.sum_total, 0) AS running_percentage
FROM t c CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(c2.Revenue) AS sum_total,
             SUM(CASE WHEN c2.Revenue >= x.Revenue THEN c2.Revenue ELSE 0 END) 
                 as sum_running
      FROM t c2 CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT c.REVENUE) x
      WHERE c."User" = c2."User"
     ) c2
ORDER BY "User", Revenue DESC;
```

I am not sure why or if this limitation is in the SQL '92 standard.  I did have it pretty well memorized 20 or so years ago, but I don't recall that particular limitation.

I should note:

- At the time of the SQL 92 standard, lateral joins were not really on the radar.  Sybase definitely had no such concept.
- Other databases *do* have problems with outer references.  In particular, they often limit the scoping to one level deep.
- The SQL Standard itself tends to highly political (that is, vendor-driven) rather than driven by actual database user requirements.  Well, over time, it does move in the right direction.

Comment: Yup, or using `CROSS APPLY` **[Demo](http://rextester.com/LOBM67950)**. It "hides" the subquery.

Comment: `(VALUES (c.REVENUE)) x(REVENUE)` does a better job, in my opinion.

Comment: Syntactic sugar it depends of taste :) First note is true, `LATERAL` (also kind of syntactic sugar) is newer concept.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such limitation in the SQL standard for `LATERAL`. `CROSS APPLY` is a vendor-specific extension from Microsoft (Oracle adopted it later for compatibility) and its limitations are obviously not owed to the ISO/IEC SQL standard, since the MS feature *pre-dates* the standard.

`LATERAL` in standard SQL is basically just a modifier for joins to allow lateral references in the join tree. There is no limit to the number of columns that can be referenced.

I wouldn't see a reason for the odd restriction to begin with. Maybe it's because `CROSS APPLY` was originally intended to allow table-valued functions, which was later extended to allow sub-`SELECT`s.

The [**Postgres** manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) explains `LATERAL` like this:

> The `LATERAL` key word can precede a sub-`SELECT FROM` item. This allows
>   the sub-`SELECT` to refer to columns of `FROM` items that appear before it
>   in the `FROM` list. (Without `LATERAL`, each sub-`SELECT` is evaluated
>   independently and so cannot cross-reference any other `FROM` item.)

The Postgres version of your query (without the more elegant window functions) can be simpler:

```
SELECT c.*
     , round(revenue        / c2.sum_total, 2) END AS percentage 
     , round(c2.running_sum / c2.sum_total, 2) END AS running_percentage 
FROM   t c, LATERAL (
   SELECT NULLIF(SUM(revenue), 0)::numeric AS sum_total  -- NULLIF, cast once
        , SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE revenue >= c.revenue) AS running_sum
   FROM   t
   WHERE  "User" = c."User"
   ) c2
ORDER  BY c."User", c.revenue DESC;
```

- Postgres 9.4+ has the more elegant aggregate `FILTER` for conditional aggregates.
- `NULLIF` makes sense, I only suggest a minor simplification.
- Cast `sum_total` to `numeric` once.
- Round result to match your desired result.

Comment: I was aware of `FILTER` feature. The Postgresql version was for demo that is why I wanted it as 1:1 as possible. SQL Sever `CROSS APPLY` version allows to cross-reference too. The point of this question how SQL Standard treat it with aggregation functions. Let's forget about `LATERAL` for a moment and get simple correlated subquery version [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/94a35/1/0) which works perfectly in MySQL/SQLite/Postgresql. Does SQL standard define to which column could we refer from agg function?

Comment: `Does SQL standard define to which column could we refer from agg function?` I'd say, to all visible columns. (Without actually investigating the SQL standards.)

Comment: Probably it is `SQL Server` restriction that enforce that all columns refrence have to be from the "same level". To the point: Is it undefinded/loose defined in standard or vendor specific.

Comment: Your cited error message does not seem to deal with *visibility* at all. Aggregated expressions with an outer reference are limited to this single outer reference. Seems vendor-specific to me.

Comment: Thank you for your time and input.

Comment: Actually `NULLIF` was intended to handle records like [`(010, 'Paul',0)`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/75b19/1/0) to avoid `Divide by zero` error. In that case entire expression will evaluate to `NULL`. But I could done it better (return proper 100%) :)

Comment: @lad2025: You are right. I somehow drifted off to `COALESCE`. `NULLIF` makes sense.